# Can you use apt in arch-linux

Tags: archlinux, apt, pacman-package-manager

I like arch, though I have to use the pacman.
Is there any way to use apt when having arch linux.
I know that pacman is arch's default package manager, but I am used to Debian-based distros.

Comment: Is your question about the game or the package manager? Read the tag [tag:pacman] description.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a programming question. It might be on-topic at [unix.se] or superuser.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could test [this AUR package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/apt/) for your own risk.
However keep in mind that AUR packages aren't part of Arch Linux, they are created by users.

Although if you just want a way to quickly learn `pacman`, which to be honest is a fascinating package manager, you could check [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Rosetta) to see the correspondence between `apt`and `pacman`.

Comment: I have already seen the page, but is there a way to use apt normally with arch linux?

Comment: `apt` is not support by Arch Linux, so the only way is through the project I linked. If that doesn't work, as a I said, the best option is to stick with `pacman`.